# Laugh to world to world laugh to you is grammatical

Tags: grammaticality, synonyms

I want to know this statement is grammatical?

> Laugh to world to world laugh to you

I had this statements too:

> Laugh to world then world will laugh to you.
>   &
>   World will laugh to you if you laugh to world.
>   &
>   Laughing to world will force the world to laugh to you

Actually I'm searching for a sentence in the same meaning that make more sense, And I think the first statement is the better one. I need to know my selected is the best one and is grammatical?

Comment: This question would be more appropriate for [English Language Learners Stack Exchange](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 3):

"Laugh and the world laughs with you; weep, and you weep alone." It's from the poem [Solitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ella_Wheeler_Wilcox) by Ella Wheeler Wilcox

Comment: It is so nice ;).